# PHP aplication to increase sequences of spaces in the string

Tags: php, string

How to write the PHP aplication that transforms a string in the way that each sequence of spaces (including single spaces) is increased by one.

For example, this string:

```
abc d  e   f
```

Should be transformed into this:

```
abc  d   e    f
```

Comment: Just do a search and replace where you replace each " " with "  ".  (that's two spaces)

Comment: This not a code writing service. We don't do your homework for you. If you can show us the code you have written and tell us how it doesn't work, we may be able to help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match a sequence of spaces, and then replace it with an additional space:

```
$newstring = preg_replace('/\s+/', '$0 ', $string);
```

`$0` in the replacement contains whatever was matched by the regular expression.

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks a lot.